# How to get state of checkbox?

Tags: dynamic

Please explain how to get state of checkbox for its usage in further calculations. And I want to keep the selection from session to session without external savings.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find answer in Help system!
It's necessary to write

`a = DynamicSetting[Checkbox[]] and evaluate it in place by Cntrl+Shft+Enter.` That`s all!

Answer (score 10):

You can use `DynamicModule`.

"Symbols specified in a `DynamicModule` will by default have their values maintained even across Mathematica sessions." (ref. [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicModule.html))

```
DynamicModule[{x},
 If[ValueQ[reportx], x = reportx, reportx = x = False];
 Checkbox[Dynamic[x, (reportx = x = #) &]], 
 Initialization :> (reportx = x)]
```

[image]

The default value of `x`/`reportx` is set to `False`.

It should only be necessary to evaluate the module once; re-evaluation does not reset anything though.

Note that you will need to keep the checkbox output cell in the notebook since the output is where the dynamic value is held.  If you delete the output cell and save the notebook the value of `x` is gone.

There is an interesting Mathgroup post from John Fultz about that [here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Feb/msg00424.html).

Comment: Recalculation of nb resets value of checkbox

Comment: Guys from Mars wrote and use this mma, I can`t understand anything for two weeks, let`s take a pen&paper

Comment: Would it work to simply make the cell non-evaluatable after the initial evaluation?

Comment: @SergeyFomin Not from Mars exactly, but a physicist from London, at least initially :)

Comment: @ celtschk - I fixed the re-evaluation check.

Comment: Congratulations!Another pair of shoes!It`s necessary to add this example to poor mma documentation

Comment: The check against True and False can be replaced with checking `ValueQ` Which is nicer, since it will work for other dynamic values as well as booleans.

Comment: @ jVincent - thanks